# Android: Start Intent from any screen

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open a screen when a particular event occurs, regardless of the screen where I am now, how do I do that?

```
Intent Iatualizar = new Intent(this, Atualizar.class); 
startActivity(Iatualizar);
```

The above code works if I'm with the screen open the program, but not work when the screen was in the background. How to make it work? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) to your Intent. If you check the log cat, it will also tell you this.

Comment: I am a beginner, could you give me an example? Thank you!

Comment: Add: `Iactualizer.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Comment: Even adding the code that I provided still does not work, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should just create a service that loads your activity when the event happens.

To do this, you can start the service when your application is loaded, and have your event receiver in your service class.  This way, even if other applications are running and your application is not in the foreground (showing on the screen) you will still be able to trigger off the event.

Android garbage collection will try to kill off your activity if it isn't in the foreground and you start running low on resources.

If you want to go a step further and make the service a foreground service, then it will theoretically be the last thing that Android will kill when it is running low on memory.  Let me know if you need a code example.

Hopefully this helps you!
Cheers

-- EDIT --

Here is a code example to get you started.

In your activities onCreate call some code similar to what you have above to launch your service. 
ie:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Intent IatualizarService = new Intent(this, AtualizarService.class); 
startService(Iatualizar);
}
```

You could also have this in your onResume if you want, (or start it from a button, or however you want this service to start).

Then create a service class like so:

```
public class AtualizarService extends Service {
private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    return START_STICKY;
  }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

// In here you can make your service a foreground service to help prevent garbage collection from occurring. 
 makeforeground();

}

    private boolean makeforeground() {
        String msg = "Turning on foreground service";
        ErrorLog.i(getApplicationContext(), TAG, msg);
        try {
            Notification notification = new Notification(
                    R.drawable.ic_dialog_info,
                    getText(R.string.notification_text),
                    System.currentTimeMillis());
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, YourMainActivity.class);
            activityIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            activityIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            activityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    activityIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this,
                    getText(R.string.notification_title),
                    getText(R.string.notification_text), pendingIntent);
            startForeground(1234567890, notification); // random id
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String error = "displayNotification Error Message: "
                    + e.getMessage() + " Cause: " + e.getCause();
            ErrorLog.e(GlobalParameters.getContext(),
                    TAG + " Notification Foreground Service", error);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
}

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return mBinder;
  }
    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        AtualizarService getService() {
            return AtualizarService .this;
        }
    }
}
```

Then inside this service class, you can add in a broadcast receiver that can trigger on any event you want. And then load up your activity if you want it to.

Cheers

Comment: It is too complex for me, you would have a simple method I execute the call without having to create a service?Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can also start a service using the code below

```
Intent Iatualizar = new Intent(this, Atualizar.class); 
Iatualizar.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(Iatualizar);
```